# SQLAlchemy how to check if a loaded objects attributes are equal to the column default

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I've got some table classes that I will be continuously adding attributes to. I want to write a function upToDate() that will return True if none of the columns are MySQL default values, and False if they are. For example, my table looks like:

```
class League(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
    numTeams = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
```

I load League id 1, and it has all of the values already populated, so it returns True. Later, I update League to look like this:

```
class League(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
    numTeams = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    firstYear = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
```

I run migrate() and update() to add the new column to the database. Now when I load League id 1, the firstYear attribute will be 0, which is the default value, which means it needs to be updated.

Answer (score 2):

I found the inspect() function in the SQLAlchemy docs, which solved the issue for me.

[Documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapping_styles.html#runtime-introspection-of-mappings-objects)

```
def upToDate(tableObject):
    defaults = {"INTEGER" : 0, "VARCHAR(128)" : ""} #could enter more data types here as necessary
    mapper = inspect(tableObject.__class__)
    for col in mapper.columns:
        name = col.name
        type = str(col.type)
        currentValue = tableObject.__getattribute__(name)
        if defaults[type] == currentValue:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: What is `col.default.arg`? ;)

Comment: I think I'm missing the point of your quesiton. Where is `col.default.arg` in my quesiton or answer?

Comment: It is not, by that's how you can access the default value (instead of hard-coding defaults in your `defaults` dictionary).

Comment: After a thought, this would work if you used default=0 in the model definition